# PhoneGap Application iOS 6 UIWebView Seems to not be filled out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova, ios6, uiwebview

I have a PhoneGap application that gets 20 px blocked from the top, which seems to me like the UIWebView is short 20px. Anyway to fix that without getting into xCode since I do not have access to that.